# Global Variables in C Between Functions

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to get to figure out how to get this print function to work outside of the function the variable is in.

```
int altitude = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    simulateAltitude();
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(altitude); // This does not work.
}

int simulateAltitude() {
    int a = 0;
    while ( a == 0 ) {
        altitude += 1;
        Serial.println(altitude); // This does work.
        delay(1);
    }
}
```

My biggest problem is the void loop() is not getting the value of altitude from the while loop in the int simulateAltitude function. This is being used on an Arduino UNO micro-controller board using C.

I am aware it is an infinite loop, it is for testing purposes only.

Comment: `int a; while(a == 0)...`: Undefined behaviour: `a` uninitialized.

Comment: Also, Arduino's first call `setup()` once, then they call `loop()` indefinitely. Are you sure that's what you want? That is, you're *never* calling the function! Also, what's the purpose of `a`? It'ld either make the function do absolutely nothing or get everything stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Please don't change your question in such a way that renders all answers to date useless. That's considered bad form :-)

Comment: The original question was poorly written and missing part of the code. The answers were finding everything except that actual issue I was having, sorry :(

Comment: Okay, if that is your final code (hopefully), I've updated my answer to tell you the exact issue you're having.

Comment: If there is an answer which solved your problems, then mark it as accepted. Otherwise tell us what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not printing the altitude from within `loop()` because `loop()` is never actually being called.

Remember this about Arduino. The `setup()` function is called once at boot time and, once it returns, the `loop()` function is called over and over again.

With the way you have it, your `setup()` function calls `simulateAltitude()` which goes into an infinite loop, so it *never* returns. It does not run `simulateAltitude()` and `loop()` concurrently.

You might be better off looking at something like:

```
void loop() {
    Serial.println(altitude);
    increaseAltitude();
}

int increaseAltitude() {
    altitude += 1;
    delay(1);
}
```

Comment: ... or anything else since the function causes UB!

Comment: Note that the OP does not initialize `a`, although your code does not have that problem.

Comment: @KemyLand, I'm not so certain that *is* UB. The standard states that the value is indeterminate if you don't initialise it, but that's different to UB, where literally *anything* can happen. It's still a bad idea, of course.

Comment: @paxdiablo: If the standard comittee could, they would make any program UB, since, for example, the computer can suddenly explode or some other stupid reason. Anyway, IMHO, it's UB, even if the standard says otherwise, because although the code behaves accordingly to the standard, it does not according to its programmer's mind.

Comment: @paxdiablo I guess that comment applies to me... I think you're right in that if the system has no trap representations then the comparison will be unspecified, but it could trap in general. Anyway this is irrelevant (unless perhaps OP is on Itanium)

Comment: @KemyLand, you've obviously not had to endure standards committees. It's not UB if it doesn't do what the programmer expects, that usually just the programmer lacking knowledge. Saying something is UB regardless of how the official standard defines it is an ... err, interesting viewpoint :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Heh, it's not the first time someone calls my biases against the standards... ahem... "interesting". And no, I've never had to endure standard committees, neither I want to. If you have had do, I'm sorry of your pain ;).

Comment: @M.M: Arduino's with an Itanium? Interesting idea to get the best and worst of both worlds!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

First of all, you need to initialize `a` and `altitude`. Give them initial values (say, `0`).

Second, you didn't setup your Serial Monitor. Add this line to your setup function:

```
Serial.begin(9600); //9600 is more common but you can set other update frequencies
```

Comment: I had that in, forgot to add it here. Will update the question. However, it appears to just spam 0 in the console.

Comment: Actually, `altitude` has static scope so it doesn't need to be initialised.

Comment: @Bondanr: Did you read my comment? The initial value of `altitude` is zero, and the Arduino will call `loop` infinitely. So, it's expected you get a infinite flood of zeroes in the console.

Comment: Ok I think I have it down this time. Missing part of the code in the original question does not help things . Yes I am intentionally running an infinite loop (Its just for testing purposes). The problem is the Serial.println in voidloop is not printing anything. Like its not getting the value from the altitude loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this code. The first is that `simulateAltitude` will never be called, so `altitude` will never update. The second problem is that neither `a` nor `altitude` are actually initialized.